# Use MAP or TEXT type of Cassandra column

Tags: python, cassandra

I want to store python `dict` objects (same structure) in Cassandra. I only want to store them in one column. I can create a Cassandra column:

1. as `MAP`
2. as `TEXT`. I can then serialize dict into json string and store it.

But not all the items in my python `dict` map to the same type, for example

```
dict = {"key_1": "abc", "key_2": 10, "key_3": True}
```

In this case, I think only Option 2 is valid? In my actual project, I have many columns to create. Some map to the same type and some don't. For convience, I want to just serialize all of them and store as `TEXT`. But this feels a bit unorthodox to me. What's the best practice?

Answer (score 2):

If you don't care about mapping each `dict` key to a CQL column then storing the whole `dict` into a CQL `text` column is generally what I recommend.

If the data type of the values are the same (they're either all texts or integers), you can store the key-value pairs in a CQL `map` collection so it's easier to retrieve the values based on the key although you already stated the values are of different data types. Cheers!